# window.performance.memory is not giving updated data but it should give

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to get memory used by a particular tab in the browser using JavaScript code. 
I have tried using window.performance.memory in Chrome. It gives me the JS heap size data but the data returned by it everytime is constant. I am creating new objects in my code (hence, memory usage should increase) but still it returns the same data everytime.
I have also used --enable-precise-memory-info argument to open my Chrome. Still same results.

Is there a way to get updated data from window.performance.memory?
Also is there any other way I can get memory usage data of a particular tab opened in the browser? I want this data to be exported in a text file so that I can use it for further analysis. 
(I have tried using Chrome's task manager and Memory Manager extension also. But I want data in a text file.)

Answer (score 0):

Try window.performance.memory after opening chrome in administrator mode.